# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression jquery.min.js isotope

Tags: jquery, str-replace, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3 and have an isotope menu item pulling in several categories that you can filter.

I know I should create a jsfiddle, but it's a bit hard to replicate this for Joomla, so I have a URL: http://pressmag.joostrap.com

The above URL is working as it should (filtering the categories) and doesn't have the the category as 'Technology & IT' (as explained below).

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<?php $data_name = htmlspecialchars($child->title); ?>
<?php $data_option = str_replace('', '', $data_name); ?>

<li class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#" data-option-value=".<?php echo $data_option; ?>"><?php echo $this->escape($child->title); ?></a></li>
```

If I rename the 'Technology' category to 'Technology & IT', the new filter will not work.

The outputted html is as follows:

```
<a href="#" data-option-value=".Technology & IT">Technology &amp; IT</a>
```

I get an error in my console that says:

**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .Technology & IT - jquery.min.js:2**

Any ideas how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Where's the code that uses that `data-option-value` attribute? Is that something you've written yourself or is it part of Joomla? Either way, I'd guess it's using the value of that attribute as a selector, and `.Technology & IT` isn't valid.

Comment: Yes... that is done via Joomla :(

Comment: You'll have to use a different value then, I guess. Avoid spaces and special characters like `&`.